# Importing GeoJSON to PostGIS with ogr2ogr and keeping geometry?

Tags: postgis, geojson, ogr2ogr

I have a .geojson file with line types that I'm trying to import into PostGIS with ogr2ogr. Following answers to similar questions on here, I tried the following:

`ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"dbname=gis user=alex" roads.geojson -nln roads`

Using pgAdmin I can see that the `roads` table was created and the data imported, but when I go to add the table in QGIS in shows up as `NoGeometry`. I've tried adding `-nlt` with `LINESTRING`, `MULTILINESTRING`, and `GEOMETRY`, but no luck.

I'm new to PostGIS and ogr2ogr--can someone please shed some light on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Check that GDAL finds geometries from the data with ogrinfo - al.

Comment: Looks like it's good, it comes back with OGRFeatures with LINESTRING like I would expect.

Comment: How about the PostGIS side, do you have a row about the new table in geometry_columns?

Comment: No, I don't even seem to have a geometry_columns view

Comment: That is strange and the reason why QGIS does not find the geometry.

Comment: I'm searching for ways to create and repopulate it manually, unless you might have a better idea?

Comment: Running `SELECT PostGIS_Version();` is returning a function does not exist error. It looks like PostGIS wasn't set up properly, so I'm going to reinstall...

Comment: @user30184 Got it. Newbie mistake, didn't realize you had to take the extra step of enabling the PostGIS extension on the database. Thanks for helping me get there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newbie mistake on my part. The PostGIS extension has to be enabled for each database before it can be used by running `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`

Comment: Yes, if this was forgotten, ogr2ogr just automatically imports data to a "plain" table with geometry in wkb_geometry binary field and probably no client (like QGIS) can read it directly. Unfortunately it tries to be too automatic and does not give even warning that PostGIS was not enabled, and it is something you very likely need.